# Error generating release keystore for kivy application

Tags: android, linux, terminal, kivy, android-keystore

I'm quite the newbie at kivy and also linux so sorry for any obvious mistakes. Anyway I typed this into terminal:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ./keystores/My1Key.keystore -alias M1K -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I fill in all the information and I get this error message:

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./keystores/My1Key.keystore (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./keystores/My1Key.keystore (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:1152)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

Please help me understand what this means and how to stop it occurring.

Sorry about my naivety, I tried to lay out the question as simply as possible, and thank you for any answers/comments. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a numpty I am, here's how I solved it:

I created a folder called "keystores" in the home directory.

:P